# Extremely high memory usage Android studio and emulator

Tags: ubuntu, qemu, android

After upgrading Android Studio to 2.3, I've encountered extremely high memory usage. Previously, I would keep my pc(including Android studio and emulator) on for several weeks, and RAM usage would stay below 12GB. However, after upgrading to 2.3, it takes about 6 hours of work until system runs out of RAM and starts using swap memory, furthermore, after full day of work, almost all swap memory is used up too.

First image is screenshot of System Monitor after reboot:
[image: After Reboot]

Second Screenshot is after single build:
[image: After single build]

`free -mh`

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            15G        5,6G        6,2G        1,1G        3,7G        8,5G
Swap:           15G          0B         15G
```

My System:
i5-6500, Ubuntu 16.10, 16GB DDR4, 16GB swap.

Is there anything else that would help? Some config files, etc.?

I will add more information later, when system starts using swap memory.

EDIT:

Idea config:

```
# custom IntelliJ IDEA VM options

-Xms512m
-Xmx8g
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=480m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-ea
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow
-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=lcd
```

Gradle properties:

```
org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx8192M
```

Tomorrow, I will try change xmx from 8gb to 4gb and see if it improves performance.

After several hours of work:
[image: After several hours]

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            15G         12G        230M        2,1G        3,0G        829M
Swap:           15G        2,0G         13G
```

As you can see, there's a third java instance running, and I looked what that is - and it's Kotlin daemon. So, in total I get 3 java instances: Kotlin, Gradle daemons and Android Studio itself.

It's seems that something has changed regarding the build caching.

Comment: Android Studio is based on JetBrains Idea platform and they have a config file that should allow you to limit a RAM usage. Try to find the config and edit it. UPDATE: also you can try to `strace` the pid of Android Studio - it should give you some insight on what process tries to do. Run `sudo strace <pid>`.

Comment: I have the same issue.